# Download and run Android APK files

Tags: downloading, apk

I want to download BitTorrent Sync to synchronize my Android and PC.

**Question #1**

What's the difference between download from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bittorrent.sync&hl=en) or [here](http://syncapp.bittorrent.com/2.0.85/)?

Since I'm not interested in register myself on Google Play, can I download an APK file from any site and run it with some sort of "double click" over the name of the file, in the same way as in Windows?

**Question #2**

After download a file where do I save it? In the smartphone RAM? In the SD Card?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the APK file with bittorrent to you PC. The other link is not usable if you don't want to register to Google Play. After downloading you transfer it to your phone. Under settings and security you have to enable unknown sources and while tapping on the transferred .APK file, it will be installed.

Comment: What does the setting "unknown sources" made to the APK file?

Comment: Apps which are installed from any source other than Google Play are unknown sources. It is for security purposes only.

Comment: And it's worth pointing out we've had a few people here who have illegal copies of paid apps that are RIDDLED with malware. So exercise caution. Don't download anything illegally, check the permissions, use common sense!

Comment: @RossC: You may right, however BitTorrent is a trustful company and while the direct link to their APK is version 2.0.64 the Google Play APK is version 1.4.56. So Google Play seems to be not update to the last versions. Moreover I want to develop some apps to my own use and it seems foolish upload an App to Google Play and then download to our own phone.

Comment: @Flavik I'm not commenting on BitTorrent, but some of the pirated stuff that users upload torrents for. If you are doing your own app you won't need to upload it anywhere, just install on your phone. As I said, I've seen a lot of people burned by pirated apps, just a common sense warning really!